# Having trouble populating a drop down list within a gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

as the title states I am currently having trouble populating a drop down list that is contained within a gridview. At first glance this seems like a relatively simple problem and I have populated many gridviews and many drop down lists in the past, however this one is being a real pain. I am relatively new to software development so any  help regarding this issue regardless of simplicity would be greatly appreciated. Below I have detailed the problem more explicitly and copied any relevant code, if there is anything I have missed I would be more than happy to supply it.

As stated before I have a drop down list (ddlPartEquipmentNew) within a gridview control (GridView3). So far there is one item in the ddl "---SELECT---" that I added as a ListItem in the aspx page.  I am trying to populate the gridview with data from my database that corresponds to a value that is currently stored in a variable on the page. I have tested my query and can confirm that it returns the appropriate values in SSMS and it looks like

SELECT EquipmentType FROM Equipment WHERE Agreement = @Agreement

Below I have posted The aspx code of the gridview and drop down.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server"
    EmptyDataText="No Claimed Parts" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataKeyNames="RecID"
    ShowFooter="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" Width="95%">

<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartEquipmentNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="EquipmentType" DataTextField="EquipmentType"
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 70px;">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePart" DataValueField="RecID"
        DataTextField="description" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px"  Height="20px"
        style="margin-left: 70px; margin-right: 110px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:textbox ID="txtUnitPriceNew" runat="server" Width="95px"/>
    <asp:textbox ID="txtTaxNew" runat="server" Width="95px" text="0"/>
    <asp:Button ID="InsertDetail" runat="server" CommandName="InsertDetail" Height="25px" Text="Add Detail" Width="85px" />
</EmptyDataTemplate>

<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" footertext="Add -->" ShowDeleteButton="True" HeaderStyle-Width="70px"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RecID" HeaderText="RecID" SortExpression="RecID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parts Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="lblDescriptionAdd" Text='<%# Bind("PartFailed") %>' runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartEquipmentEdit" runat="server" DataValueField="Agreement" DataTextField="EquipmentType"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 70px;">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePart" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="description" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("RepairID")%>' AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartEquipmentInsert" runat="server" DataValueField="Agreement" DataTextField="EquipmentType"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 70px;">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePart" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="description" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="270px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part Cost Requested" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="lblUnitPrice" Text='<%# Bind("PartCost", "{0:C}") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtUnitPriceEdit" Text='<%# Bind("PartCost") %>' Enabled="true" runat="server"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtUnitPriceInsert" Text='<%# Bind("PartCost") %>' runat="server" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tax" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbTaxTotal" Text='<%# Bind("Tax", "{0:C}")%>' runat="server" CommandArgument="Part" OnClick="lblTaxTotal_Click"/>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPartGST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("GST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPartPST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("PST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPartQST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("QST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPartHST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("HST")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="lblTaxTotalEdit" Text='<%# Bind("Tax")%>' Enabled="true" runat="server"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtTaxTotalInsert" Text="0" runat="server" Enabled="true" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insert New" HeaderStyle-Width="85px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" Text="" runat="server" Width="75px"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Insert" runat="server" CommandName="InsertNewDetail" Height="22px" Text="Insert" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

In order to populate the drop down list I have associated it with an asp:SqlDataSource control below.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WarrantyConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT EquipmentType FROM Equipment WHERE Agreement = @Agreement">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In the vb.net code behind I have declared the parameter in the page load event as seen below

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Decrypt et get params
    MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = True
    hashtableParams = RedirectionHandler.EncryptedRequest(Request.QueryString("data"))
    'SqlDataSourcePartEquipment.SelectParameters.Add("@Agreement", hashtableParams("agreementNumber"))
    'If Page.IsPostBack Then
    'Dim wcICausedPostBack As WebControl = CType(GetControlThatCausedPostBack(TryCast(sender, Page)), WebControl)
    'Dim indx As Integer = wcICausedPostBack.TabIndex
    'Dim ctrl = _
    'From control In wcICausedPostBack.Parent.Controls.OfType(Of WebControl)() _
    'Where control.TabIndex > indx _
    'Select control
    'ctrl.DefaultIfEmpty(wcICausedPostBack).First().Focus()
    'End If

    'Dim SClaimID As String = CType(Session.Item("SClaimID"), String)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim agreement As String = hashtableParams("agreementNumber")
        Dim claimID As String

        If hashtableParams.Count > 0 AndAlso Not IsNothing(hashtableParams("claimID")) Then
            claimID = hashtableParams("claimID")
            Session("ClaimID") = claimID
        Else
            claimID = CType(Session.Item("ClaimID"), String)
        End If

        Me.txtAgreement.Text = agreement
        Me.txtOtherInvoice.Text = "I'm Working"

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(claimID) Then
            objCn.Open()
            objSelectCmd.Connection = objCn
            objSelectCmd.CommandText = "Select * From Claim Where ClaimNumber = @ClaimID"
            objSelectCmd.Parameters.Add("ClaimID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = claimID

            objSelectCmd.Connection = objCn
            objDa.SelectCommand = objSelectCmd
            objDa.Fill(objDs, "Claim")
            objDataTable = objDs.Tables("Claim")
            objCurrentRow = objDataTable.Rows(0)
            Me.txtAgreement.Text = objCurrentRow("Agreement").ToString
            Me.txtServicerNumber.Text = objCurrentRow("AccountNumber").ToString
            'Me.txtCNumber.Text = objCurrentRow("AccountNumber").ToString
            Me.lblClaimNumber.Text = objCurrentRow("ClaimNumber").ToString
            lblCreationDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(objCurrentRow("CreateDate").ToString).ToShortDateString
            Me.txtProblem.Text = objCurrentRow("ProblemDescription").ToString
            Me.txtSubmitDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(objCurrentRow("ReceivedDate").ToString).ToShortDateString
            Me.txtWorkPerformed.Text = objCurrentRow("WorkPerformed").ToString
            Me.txtServiceDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(objCurrentRow("FailDate").ToString).ToShortDateString
            Me.txtWorkInvoice.Text = objCurrentRow("WorkInvoice").ToString
            Me.txtOtherInvoice.Text = objCurrentRow("OtherInvoice").ToString
            Me.lblClaimStatus.Text = objCurrentRow("Status").ToString
            SqlDataSourcePartEquipment.SelectParameters.Add("@Agreement", hashtableParams(agreementNumber))
```

(There is much more code in the Page_load() event, and if required I can supply it)
When I execute this code and navigate to the web form in question I receive an exception error "Must declare the scalar variable "@Agreement". To my knowledge I am declaring the @Agreement variable in the last line of what I posted of the Page_Load event. I have also used the "agreement" variable seen earlier in the page load event and when I use that, I don't receive the exception error but my drop down still isn't populated.

Whats confusing me so much is that every variable or control that stores the value I need for my parameter either populates nothing to my drop down or I receive the exception mentioned above.

If anyone has an idea as to why this could be happening I would greatly appreciate some input here as I am at a loss as to what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you have a lot of moving parts.

But, how to setup a combo box in a gv?

Say this simple markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-striped" Width="50%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"     />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate Hotel">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRank" runat="server"
                DataValueField="ID"
                DataTextField="Rating" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" CssClass="btn" 
OnClick="cmdSave_Click"  />                          

<asp:Button ID="cmdAddNew" runat="server" Text="New Hotel" CssClass="btn"
    style="margin-left:20px" />
```

And code to load this up is this:

```
Dim rstRank As New DataTable ' to load cbo box

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    ' load combo box data
    rstRank = MyRst("SELECT ID, Rating from tblRating ORDER BY ID")

    ' load gv
    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    GHotels.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    GHotels.DataBind()

End Sub

Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rst As New DataTable

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rst

End Function
```

And we get this:

[image]

The only extra part? We need to load up each row combo, and ALSO set the value from the data. We use the row data bound event, and this code:

```
Protected Sub GHotels_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GHotels.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        ' load combo box with choices
        Dim cboRank As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("cboRank")
        cboRank.DataSource = rstRank
        cboRank.DataBind()
        ' add blank row "select"
        cboRank.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select", "0"))

        ' NOW set combo to current choice in database
        Dim rowData As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
        If Not IsDBNull(rowData("Rating")) Then
            cboRank.SelectedValue = rowData("Rating")
        End If

    End If
```

So, in a nutshell, the above is the basic approch. However, you have a boatload of markup, and seem to have the 2 combo boxes repeated at least 3 times. You need to VAST VAST reduce the amount of markup you have. You with a somewhat different approach reduce that markup to what I have above - and have editing. But, I would not use edit templates, and I would not even use a whole new alternatiing template for JUST display of bands (note how I used the style class = table to make the grid look nice, and added table-striped to alternate the bands). This is a bootstrap class - and by default most asp.net sites do have bootstrap installed.

If  you need editing, then I would suggest a clean and simple layout using listview in place of grid view. it tends to mean VAST less markup, and is less convoluted.

And for each asp.net control, you don't have to wrap it around a template.

So, to allow editing of the data above, and a simple save to save all edits. Then I would use this (a list view).

```
   <style> 
       .borderhide input {border:none}
       .borderhide textarea {border:none}
   </style>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td><asp:Textbox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' Width="100px"/></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'   Width="100px" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>'     Width="100px" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' Width="100px" /></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' 
                TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="60" /></td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRank" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="Rating" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" class="table table-bordered borderhide" >
            <tr runat="server" style="">
                <th runat="server">First Name</th>
                <th runat="server">Last Name</th>
                <th runat="server">City</th>
                <th runat="server">Hotel Name</th>
                <th runat="server">Description</th>
                <th runat="server">Rating</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" CssClass="btn" 
OnClick="cmdSave_Click"  />                          

<asp:Button ID="cmdAddNew" runat="server" Text="New Hotel" CssClass="btn"
    style="margin-left:20px" />
```

But with above, I can have ONE easy save button - saves all edits. No messy edit template, no messy itemtemplates for each row. No noting. And the above allows editing of all rows - one simple save button sends all changes to the database.

so, as listview, we get this:

[image]

I can post the save code, but this question was about setting up a combo box.

But, to "save" all and any edits, the above markup remains "as is", and we save boatloads of markup, and boatloads of code behind here.

So the ONE set of markup allows:

```
Display of data
Editing of data
Save of data
```

Now, I did original use the wizard and the datasouce it puts on the page. I then just went on a delete hunt, and removed all the templates - only need itemtemplate and I am done for display, and editing of the data.

## Edit: Part 2 - how to save data back to database

So, in this 2nd example, we will use a Listview, we will have ONE simple easy save button for the data.

Users on a web page - or even having used Excel, they are VERY used to this idea. Having some "edit and cancel" in the row is CONFUSING. If you want a in-line edit button - I suggest popping up some kind of details view - but that's another day and post.

So, assuming we follow my suggesting here?

We try as HARD as heck to NOT do calulatons and data processing in the GridView or in this case the listview.

Our list view is ONLY for display, and edit, but ALL data operations are to occur at our data table.

So, we are going to LOAD the table, and persit that table for the life of this page. The fact that we display this table of data? We don't care.

We think, we breathe, we work from that table at all times and as much as possible. We THEN update the display when required.

Now, I could have taken the sample markup above. But, lets add some tax calculations - this will be more code (and more markup), but without such, then the example not of great use.

Ok, so our markup:

So, we now in place of labels, we drop in textbox, or dropdown or whatever control(s) we need in this table/grid like layout.

So, our markup is now this:

```
   <style> 
       .borderhide input {border:none;background-color:transparent}
       .borderhide textarea {border:none;background-color:transparent}
   </style>

    <div style="width:70%">
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
       <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Textbox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' Width="70px" /></td>
        <td><asp:Textbox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' Width="70px"/></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>'       Width="70px" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' Width="100px" /></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' 
                TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="52" /></td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRank" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="Rating" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNights" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nights") %>' 
                 width="35px" 
                OnTextChanged="txtNights_TextChanged"/>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
            <asp:Label ID="txtPerNight" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NightRate", "{0:C0}") %>' />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right" >
            <asp:Label ID="txtTaxes" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("Taxes", "{0:C2}") %>'  width="40px" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right">
            <asp:Label ID="txtTaxAndAmount" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("PriceAndTax", "{0:C2}") %>'   />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
             <button id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn" 
                 onserverclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick" tabindex="-1" 
                 onclick="if (!confirm('Really delete')) {return false}" >
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
         <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" 
            class="table  table-hover table-bordered table-striped borderhide" >
        <tbody>
            <tr runat="server" style="">
                <th runat="server" style="width:60px">First</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:60px">Last</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:60px">City</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:70px" >Hotel Name</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:140px" >Description</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:100px">Rating</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:60px">Nights</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:60px" >Per<br />Night</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:60px">Taxes</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:60px">Amount</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:60px"></th>
            </tr>

            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <%-- skip 7 boxes --%>
                <td></td><td></td>
                <td></td><td></td>
                <td></td><td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align:right">Total</td>
                <td style="text-align:right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalTax" runat="server" Width="62px">
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalSum" runat="server" Width="62px">
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

Its more markup then before - but we added a footer - and we wanted totals. So, each feature, each goal? It costs time and efforts.

So, now code has to PERSIT our data table.

So, we declare some values at the CLASS level - so all code in the page can use that table.

We have this code to load things up:

```
Dim rstRank As New DataTable    ' to load cbo box
Dim rstData As New DataTable    ' our data table

Dim gTotalAmount As Double = 0  ' footer totals
Dim gTotalTax As Double = 0

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
        Session("rstData") = rstData
        Session("rstRank") = rstRank
        DisplayUpdate()
    Else
        rstData = Session("rstData")
        rstRank = Session("rstRank")
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    ' load combo box
    rstRank = MyRst("SELECT ID, Rating from tblRating ORDER BY ID")
    ' load gv
    rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")

End Sub

Sub DisplayUpdate()

    GridToTable()   ' send grid to rstData table
    Calculator()    ' table calulations
    ListView1.DataSource = rstData
    ListView1.DataBind()
    ShowTotal()     ' show the total in footing

End Sub
```

And we see this:

[image]

Now, I did decide in place of asp:button, to use a standard button. but when you add runat=server - they WORK very much the same. Only reason for this is I wanted to add bootstrap icons to the buttons - no other reason for this.

(this does mean we can't double click on buttons to create event - use the markup = intel-sense will pop options to create code behind click event.

So, right below the grid, we have this markup for the 3 buttons.

```
        <button id="cmdSave" runat="server" class="btn"                
            onserverclick="cmdSave_Click" tabindex="-1" >
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"> Save&ensp;/&ensp;Update</span>
        </button>
             
        <button id="cmdAddNew3" runat="server" class="btn"
            style="margin-left:20px"
            onserverclick="cmdAddNew_Click" tabindex="-1" >
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"> New&ensp;Hotel</span>
        </button>

        <button id="cmdUnDo" runat="server" class="btn" 
            style="margin-left:20px"
            onserverclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick" tabindex="-1" >
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"> Undo</span>
        </button>
```

Ok, so now the routines.

we need Send grid to table

we need save rstData back to SQL server.

we need the calulator.

So, we have these small routines, and we have ONE calulator routine - not a bunch and this does NOT operate against the display - only the data table.

So, we have:

GridToTable.

This without question is the Rossetta stone routine here. Once we can send grid values back to rstData - then we are HOME free!!!

```
Sub GridToTable()

    ' send grid rows back to persited table

    For Each gRow As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items

        ' Get database PK value
        Dim PK As Integer = ListView1.DataKeys(gRow.DataItemIndex).Item("ID")

        Dim drT() As DataRow = rstData.Select("ID = " & PK, "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
        If drT.Length > 0 Then
            Dim OneDataRow As DataRow
            OneDataRow = drT(0)
            OneDataRow.Item("FirstName") = CType(gRow.FindControl("txtFirst"), TextBox).Text
            OneDataRow.Item("LastName") = CType(gRow.FindControl("txtLast"), TextBox).Text
            OneDataRow.Item("City") = CType(gRow.FindControl("txtCity"), TextBox).Text
            OneDataRow.Item("Description") = CType(gRow.FindControl("txtDescription"), TextBox).Text
            OneDataRow.Item("Nights") = CType(gRow.FindControl("txtNights"), TextBox).Text
            ' combo box
            Dim cboRank As DropDownList = gRow.FindControl("cboRank")
            If cboRank.Text = "Select" Then
                OneDataRow("Rating") = DBNull.Value
            Else
                OneDataRow("Rating") = cboRank.SelectedItem.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Now, above could have check boxes, (drop down list). It don't matter, but key concept is a routine to send text box (columns you want to edit) back to this table.

Our calculation routines - again, against the table - no display update.

```
Sub Calculator()

    ' process data - at persited table level ONLY!
    gTotalAmount = 0
    gTotalTax = 0
    For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstData.Rows
        If OneRow.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted Then
            OneRow("Price") = OneRow("Nights") * OneRow("NightRate")
            OneRow("Taxes") = OneRow("Price") * OneRow("GST")
            OneRow("PriceAndTax") = OneRow("Price") + OneRow("Taxes")
            gTotalAmount += OneRow("PriceAndTax")
            gTotalTax += OneRow("Taxes")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub ShowTotal()

    Dim MySumTax As Label = ListView1.FindControl("lblTotalTax")
    MySumTax.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", gTotalTax)

    Dim MySum As Label = ListView1.FindControl("lblTotalSum")
    MySum.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", gTotalAmount)

End Sub
```

Code to send all edits, deletes and add to the sql server database in ONE shot.

```
Sub SaveTableToDB()

    ' save/write data back to database
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * From tblHotelsA", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Our garbage can row delete button.

```
Protected Sub cmdDelete_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' save any edits BACK to table before delete
    ' this ONLY delets from persited table - not SQL server.
    GridToTable()
    Dim btn As HtmlButton = sender
    Dim gRow As ListViewItem = btn.NamingContainer
    Dim PK As Integer = ListView1.DataKeys(gRow.DataItemIndex).Item("ID")

    Dim OneDataRow As DataRow = rstData.Select("id = " & PK)(0)
    OneDataRow.Delete()
    DisplayUpdate()

End Sub
```

code to add new row - NOTE AGAIN we do this against this persited table - it not been yet saved to the database. That means if we delete rows, add rows, and then cancel out - it all is un-done!!!

```
Protected Sub cmdAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim NewRow As DataRow = rstData.NewRow

    ' setup defaults - make sure no nulls for number values
    NewRow("HST") = 0 ' GetHst() routine
    NewRow("PST") = 0 ' GetPst() routine
    NewRow("GST") = 0.05
    NewRow("Active") = True
    NewRow("Nights") = 0
    NewRow("NightRate") = 123
    rstData.Rows.Add(NewRow)

    ListView1.DataSource = rstData
    ListView1.DataBind()
    Debug.Print(ListView1.DataKeys.Count)

End Sub
```

That is quite much all you need.

but, we don't nag and prompt the user to death with cancel, and edit buttons. But then again, either does Excel, right???

Undo button:

```
Protected Sub cmdUnDo_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    LoadData()
    Session("rstData") = rstData
    Session("rstRank") = rstRank
    DisplayUpdate()

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @Albert D. Kallal, Thanks for replying to the post, your information has helped me out a lot with both this problem and when I need to do more like this in the future.

Comment: As noted I can post the save button code - since again it's far less code then all of the code and markup you have so far. You really don't want say 3 set's of combo boxes such as you have.

Comment: Hey @Albert D. Kallal, Thank you for the offer and I would be happy to take you up on it and see the save button code.  I think it will help me greatly going forward.

Comment: Yes, not only is layout of the listview much better - less markup then a gv (when it starts to get complex), the save code also saves a HUGE boatload of code. Busy day - but this evening I'll post the code as to how you can use a simple save button to save all edits in this table display - of which we now will assume is a listview.  GV are great for table and columns display - but as you get more complex, then listview wins this race hands down.

Comment: did not yet post - but when I do, I'll put a comment here - and you get that red notification that a common exists. So, as soon as I post the example, I'll also post in comments here that I done so - this will be this evening. (Friday)

Comment: Well, its Saturday evening - but see part two - I show the edit list view code. While it is a bit more code, it STILL FAR less then a huge pile of markup, and HUGE pile of sql data sources on the page. It is rather clean, and the pattern can be reused for other editing and projects.